# bash script to pattern match and delete files

Tags: bash, shell

Problem: In a directory, I have files of the following form:

```
<account-number>-<invoice-number>, an example being:

123456-3456789
123456-6789023
123456-2568907
...
456789-2347890
456789-2344357

etc.
```

What I want to do is, if there are more than 1 invoices for the same account, delete all except the latest. If there's only one, leave it alone.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: How do you tell what the account numbers are?  Before the `-`?

Comment: Yes, for 123456-3456789 123456 is the account number, 3456789 is the invoice number. So in the example above, if 123456-3456789 is latest, I want to delete the other two beginning with 123456 etc.

Comment: And the latest invoice is decided by timestamp or by the invoice number?

Comment: Does Anubhava's solution not work for you or do you want something more elegant (read one liner)?

Comment: Didn't work. All the latest files didn't get moved over to tmp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this awk based script:

```
mkdir _tmp
ls -rt *-*|awk -F'-' '{a[$1]=$0} END{for (i in a) system("mv " a[i] " _tmp/")}'
```

Once you're satisfied with the files in `./_tmp/` remove all files from current directory and move files over.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a timestamp check?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure bash solution (replace `echo` with `rm` when you validate it)

```
for file1 in *-*
do 
    IFS=- arr=($file1)
    for file2 in "${arr[0]}"*
    do 
        [ "$file1" -nt "$file2" ] && echo "$file2"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice one in Bash:
(pseudo "in place" processing)

```
#!/bin/bash -e

ADIR="/path/to/account/directory"
TMP="$ADIR.tmp"

mkdir "$TMP" && rmdir "$TMP" && mv "$ADIR" "$TMP" && mkdir "$ADIR"

while IFS=- read ACCNT INVOICE < <( ls -t1 "$TMP" )
do
    mv "$TMP/$ACCNT-$INVOICE" "$ADIR/$ACCNT-$INVOICE" && rm "$TMP/$ACCNT"*
done

rmdir "$ADIR.tmp"
```

what it does:

1 first move the a(ccounts) directory to a temporary directory. (is atomic)
 2 in a loop: list newest invoice, move it to the new directory, delete invoices with same account.
 3 remove temporary directory

**PROs:**
solid, safe, short, reasonably fast and halts on serious errors

**CONs:**
Very definitive, be sure to have always a backup

**Comment:**
You may have noticed `mkdir "$TMP" && rmdir "$TMP"`
This is on purpose: rmdir gives the same returnvalue for "dir not exist" as "dir not empty"
so instead of checking which of the two it is 
`[ -d $DIRNAME ] && { rmdir $DIRNAME || exit }`
I used the above construction.

Also the `ls -t1 "$TMP` may be at a strange place at first sight
But it is OK, every iteration it will be executed again (but only the first line is read)